# Can't call function. Is there a setting that controls this?

Tags: r

I created a simple function.

```
kelvin_to_celsius <- function(temp_K) {
  temp_C <- temp_K - 273.15
  return(temp_C)
}
```

I put it in here:

```
C:\Users\Excel\Documents\kelvin_to_celsius.r

getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Excel/Documents"
```

I'm calling the function and getting an error.

```
kelvin_to_celsius(150)
Error in kelvin_to_celsius(150) : 
  could not find function "kelvin_to_celsius"
```

Am I missing something here???

Comment: Have you `source`'d that file?

Comment: Conceptually, think about what a mess you'd have if every variable, function, etc were present in your current environment just because they were defined in files within your working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably need to source it with `source("kelvin_to_celsius.r")`

```
# > kelvin_to_celsius(150)
# Error in kelvin_to_celsius(150) : 
#   could not find function "kelvin_to_celsius"
# > source("kelvin_to_celsius.r")
# > kelvin_to_celsius(150)
# [1] -123.15
```

Comment: Yeah, source worked.  I haven't used any R functions in a few months; just worked with Python recently.  I don't remember every having to source a UDF.  Is that a new thing now?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't think `source` is a new thing. cheers!